# Passing data from ngx-bootstrap Modal to Component

Tags: html, angular, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I have an array drivers in my component. I'm showing a ngx-bootstrap modal with a value fullname from the drivers array when i click a button in the component. Now i want to get the data back from the modal like which name is selected. How to do that?

```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-round" (click)="staticModal.show()">{{'Assign Driver' | translate}}
  </button>`

  <div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal"
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-static-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-static-name" class="modal-title pull-left">Select Drivers</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="staticModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div *ngFor= "let dri of drivers">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio">
            <label>{{dri.fullname}}</label>
          </div>
       <div class = "modal-footer">   
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="staticModal.hide()" >Select Driver</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="staticModal.hide()">Cancel</button>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to get value of the selected radio button in the component. And when the modal is closed i want to perform the method placeorder() which i already  How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.data = //'your data want to sent in model';
    modalRef.result.then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

In Model component

```
@input() data : any;


  closel() {
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    this.activeModal.close(data);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is no way related to my question

Comment: so you have to send input in model window